# Combobox Selected Index is changing to 0 when data is appended to it

Tags: c#, .net

Hi I am using the following code in the form load

```
Combobox1.DataSource=GetItems();
```

Then by default first item is selected.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose your ComboBox has the DropDownStyle property set to DropDownList. When it is, setting the Datasource automatically sets the SelectedIndex to 0 (first element in the list). You could write:

```
Combobox1.DataSource=GetItems();
Combobox1.SelectedIndex = -1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not appending data, you're replacing it entirely. So the SelectedIndex will be reset. You could remember it and then set it back like so

```
int oldIndex = Combobox1.SelectedIndex;
Combobox1.DataSource= GetItems();
Combobox1.SelectedIndex = oldIndex; //should check to see if the new list is long enough.
```